# Bagging for continuous variable

Tags: machine-learning, bagging

I am using bagging approach in R to predict average Ozone data. I have a confusion that, can I use bagging method to predict average Ozone? Since it is continuous variable. I read some articles where they applied bagging approach for binary variables (class).

Comment: I think you can use weighting the results instead of max voting in binary case.